# Monthly Report - SQL

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

I have the table below, how would I select in SQL the last date of each month (from the list) in each categoryID?

I want to end up with something in the line off:

CategoryID | Current | Date

```
1      |    5    | 2016-09-30
1      |    3    | 2016-10-30
1      |    7    | 2016-11-30
1      |    2    | 2016-12-30
```

etc. as history builds up.

Image :

[image]

Comment: I don't recognize those dates as the last dates of months.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.)

Comment: @GordonLinoff The dates are recorded every Friday, thus not necessarily the last day of the month on the calendar. For the example I made dates up to show the end result I want.

Comment: @jarlh what do you mean by "dsms"? I am new to programming and still l have loads to learn.

Comment: @ExpressDude: DBMS stands for DataBase Management System. In short, what database do you use? Usually, you'd say something like MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server (T-SQL being the language), PostgreSQL, or even MongoDB...

Comment: The UI looks like SQL Management Studio, so my money on T-SQL

Comment: @Martheen You are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Considering you're using `MySQL`, since you haven't mentioned.

Suppose this is your table named : **`'Dummy'`**

```
cat_id  current  date     
------  -------  --------
     1        5  2016-09-30
     1        3  2016-10-30
     1        7  2016-11-30
     1        2  2016-12-30
     2        4  2016-10-31
     2        6  2016-10-04
```

Executing this query :

```
select 
  o.cat_id,
  (SELECT DISTINCT 
    a.date 
  from
    Dummy a 
  where a.cat_id = o.cat_id 
  ORDER BY date DESC 
  LIMIT 1) as 'date' 
from
  Dummy o 
group by o.cat_id ;
```

Gives you the Latest date of each category :

```
cat_id  date        
------  ------------
     1  2016-12-30  
     2  2016-10-31
```

**EDIT**

This is supposed to work specifically for your table. Just replace "yourTable" with the table's actual name.

```
select 
  o.CategoryID,
  o.StockCurrent
  (SELECT DISTINCT 
    a.RecordAdded 
  from
    yourTable a 
  where a.CategoryID = o.CategoryID 
  ORDER BY RecordAdded DESC 
  LIMIT 1) as 'RecordAdded' 
from
  yourTable o 
group by o.CategoryID ;
```

**EDIT 2** :

This Query returns the latest date of each month within a certain category. Hope this is what you want.

```
SELECT 
  o.CategoryID,
  o.StockCurrent,
  o.RecordAdded 
FROM
  `yourTable` o 
WHERE o.RecordAdded IN 
  (SELECT 
    MAX(i.RecordAdded) 
  FROM
    `yourTable` i 
  GROUP BY MONTH(i.RecordAdded)) 
GROUP BY o.CategoryID,
  o.RecordAdded ;
```

Suppose the table contains the following sample data:

```
CategoryID  StockCurrent  RecordAdded  
----------  ------------  -------------
         1             5  2016-09-01   
         1             3  2016-09-02   
         1             7  2016-10-01   
         1             2  2016-10-02   
         2             4  2016-09-01   
         2             6  2016-09-02   
         2            66  2016-10-01   
         2            77  2016-10-02
```

Running this query returns the following result set :

```
CategoryID  StockCurrent  RecordAdded  
----------  ------------  -------------
         1             3  2016-09-02   
         1             2  2016-10-02   
         2             6  2016-09-02   
         2            77  2016-10-02
```

Comment: I need the last "RecordAdded" date from each month per category.

Comment: @ExpressDude Check the Edit 2 now and let me know if it helps

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to approaches to do this, one of them could be using windowing function rownumber. Within the CTE (WITH) you get local order of the records within date(using covert to get rid of the time here)+CategoryID partition by datetime DESC (-> first is latest). You need to do this because you cannot use windowing functions in WHERE clause. Then, in the main query, you actually use this CTE as your source table and get only the latest record per partition.

```
WITH LocallyOrdered AS (
  SELECT CategoryID, 
  StockCurrent,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY CategoryID, CONVERT(date, RecordAdded) 
    ORDER BY RecordAdded DESC) 
  AS RowNumberOneIsLatest
  FROM OriginalTable)
SELECT CategoryID, StockCurrent FROM LocallyOrdered WHERE RowNumberOneIsLatest = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
WITH Temp As
(
select CategoryId, [Current], RecordAdded,
Dense_Rank() over( partition by CategoryId order by RecordAdded desc) as CatergoryWiseRank
from tblCategory
)
select CategoryId, [Current], RecordAdded from Temp where CatergoryWiseRank=1
```

Comment: Sorry no it returns the same results as selecting everything.

Comment: You want one row for each categoryID (group by categoryID)?

Comment: between which DBMS? also put where clause if u want just category id 1

Comment: adding the where clause is fine, that I can do. Working on 4 weeks per month, one will have 4 records per month per categoryID. I want a list of the last record from each month per categoryID. Over a 12 month period I will end up with 12 records per categoryID.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
CASE MONTH(date_field) 
WHEN 1 THEN 'Enero'
WHEN 2 THEN 'Febrero'
WHEN 3 THEN 'Marzo'
WHEN 4 THEN 'Abril'
WHEN 5 THEN 'Mayo'
WHEN 6 THEN 'Junio'
WHEN 7 THEN 'Julio'
WHEN 8 THEN 'Agosto'
WHEN 9 THEN 'Septiembre'
WHEN 10 THEN 'Octubre'
WHEN 11 THEN 'Noviembre'
WHEN 12 THEN 'Diciembre'
END as Mes, COUNT(date_field) as cantidad FROM nacimientos 
WHERE YEAR(date_field)='1991'
GROUP BY MONTH(date_field)asc
```

Result
[image]